# Magento Send Order method

Tags: magento, sendmail

I've been looking for hours to find the right method which sends the order to the customer after payment.
I found this file: /app/code/_core/Mage/Sales/Model/order.php which contains the method

```
/**
 * Send email with order data
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
 */
public function sendNewOrderEmail()
```

When I completely remove this class, the order is still sent. (huh?)
Yes, I cleared my cache!

What is the right sendMail method?

Comment: Yes that the method that send email, do you have any other custom module that may have modify this? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: At first, thanks for your comment.
I am trying to send a custom mail depening on the shipping method. The only thing I need is an extension of the send method so I can check wich shipping method is selected so I can send an alternative mail to the customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a order email to a customer you can do

```
$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
$_order->sendNewOrderEmail();
```

sendNewOrderEmail() is define in /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php (assuming that there is not custom module that modify it)